# creating json string using JSONObject and JSONArray

Tags: java, jquery, json

I have data like this:

NewsItem :

- id
- title
- date
- txt

There may be many NewsItems say 10. I have to send them to jquery.

I am doing this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

for(int i = 0 ; i< list.size() ; i++){
    p = list.get(i);
    arr.put(p.getId());
    arr.put(p.getTitle());
    arr.put(new MyDateFormatter().getStringFromDateDifference(p.getCreationDate()));
    arr.put(getTrimmedText(p.getText()));
    obj.put(""+i,arr);
    arr = new JSONArray();
}
```

This will create a JSON string like this : `{"1":["id","title","date","txt"],"2":[......and so on...`

Is that correct way of doing this?

How can I parse this string so that I can get each news item object in jQuery so that I can access attr.

Like this:

```
obj.id,
obj.title
```

Or if this is wrong way of creating JSON string, please suggest some better way with example of parsing in jQuery.

Comment: downvoter :  here is a comment area for you....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe that you're organizing your data backwards. It seems that you want to use an array of `NewsItems`, and if so, then your java JSON generation code should look like this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

for(int i = 0 ; i< list.size() ; i++)
{
    p = list.get(i);

    obj.put("id", p.getId());
    obj.put("title", p.getTitle());
    obj.put("date". new MyDateFormatter().getStringFromDateDifference(p.getCreationDate()));
    obj.put("txt", getTrimmedText(p.getText()));

    arr.put(obj);

    obj = new JSONObject();
}
```

Now your JSON string will look something like this:

```
[{"id": "someId", "title": "someTitle", "date": "dateString", "txt": "someTxt"},
 {"id": "someOtherId", "title": "someOtherTitle", "date": "anotherDateString", "txt": "someOtherTxt"},
 ...]
```

Assuming that your NewsItem gettors return `Strings`. The JSONObject method `put` is overloaded to take primitive types also, so if, e.g. your `getId` returns an `int`, then it will be added as a bare JSON `int`. I'll assume that `JSONObject.put(String, Object)` calls `toString` on the value, but I can't verify this.

Now in javascript, you can use such a string directly:

```
var arr =
    [{"id": "someId", "title": "someTitle", "date": "dateString", "txt": "someTxt"},
     {"id": "someOtherId", "title": "someOtherTitle", "date": "anotherDateString", "txt": "someOtherTxt"}];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    alert(arr[i].title); // should show you an alert box with each first title
```

Comment: how can i traverse each object in a loop....
arr[0] .. arr[1] would be ok but if i don't know number of items then how can i access them ???

Comment: @JAVAGeek: javascript arrays have a `length` property, see edit

Comment: what library is used? javax.json?

Comment: @pb2q you might want to change `arr.put(obj);` to `arr.add(obj);` to avoid `The method put(JSONObject) is undefined for the type 
 JSONArray` error.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the json object is the same as a dictionary/map where you have keys and values assigned to those keys, so what you want to construct would be something like this:

```
{"1": {"title": "my title", "date": "17-12-2011", "text": "HELLO!"}, "2": ....}
```

where the "1" is the id and the contents is another dictionary/map with the info.

lets say you assigned the object to a variable named **my_map**, now you will be able to handle it as:

```
 my_map.1.title
 my_map.3.text
 ...
```

to iterate over it just use:

```
for (info in my_map){
    data = my_map[info];
    //do what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For converting JSON object to JSON string use

```
JSON.stringify(json_object)
```

For reverse use:

```
JSON.parse(json_string)
```

Comment: If you're using json-simple you can use toJSONString() method

Comment: What library is this from?

Comment: @Vic It is available with javascript:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way -

```
final JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

for(int i = 0 ; i< list.size() ; i++) {
    final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    p = list.get(i);
    obj.add("id", p.getId());
    obj.add("title", p.getTitle());
    obj.add("date", new MyDateFormatter().getStringFromDateDifference(p.getCreationDate()));
    obj.add("txt", getTrimmedText(p.getText()));
    arr.add(obj);
}
```

This will generate

`[{"id": 1, "date": 222, "title": "abc", "txt": "some text"}, {...}]`

Now, when you parse the json at client end, you can iterate over the array and for each json object you can access as -

`obj.id` or `obj["id"]`

Comment: it is not obj.add("","");, it is obj.put("","");

Comment: list ? i have 2 string.

Comment: the 'obj' is not getting cleared up at the end of for loop. It requires, something like obj = new JSONObject();  in the end of every iteration in for loop